# Can't connect two element in one table. sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to make m2m connection inside one table, but got an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Products.compatibilities - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'сompatibilites'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.
```

My code:

```
сompatibilites = db.Table('сompatibilites', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('left_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id')),
    db.Column('right_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'))
)

class Products(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    type = db.Column(db.String(63))
    text = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    specs = db.relationship('Specs', backref='product', lazy='dynamic')
    slides = db.relationship('ProductSlides', backref='product', lazy='dynamic')
    img = db.Column(db.String(6), unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    compatibilities = db.relationship('Products', secondary=сompatibilites, backref=db.backref('compatibilities', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a junction table without relations. Just a table with items ids